# how to make dotted progress indicator component with react hooks?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to make a dotted progress indicator with react-hooks.
So I have four dots which indicate progress. it's going from full to empty, if it's four dots it's green, three yellow, two - redish and one is red.
I want to control the color and number of dots lit up with props and do it with react-hooks.

The only thing close to it I could find was "Dotted progress bar" on codepen, but it's still different from what I want.

I am expecting the output to be that if I pass 0-25% it lights only one dot with red color, on 50-75% yellow and so on.

I've been trying for some time now, the furthest I've gone is this:

```
const OnGoingRequest = ({ image, name, profession, progress, color }) => {
  const [dotColor, setDotColor] = useState('#c4c4dd')
  if (progress > 0 && progress <= 25) {
    setDotColor('red')
  } else if (progress > 25) {
    setDotColor('blue')
  }
  return (
    <EachReview>
      <UserContainer>
        <UserImage src={image} />
        <UserInfoContainer>
          <UserName>{name} </UserName>
          <UserProffession>{profession} </UserProffession>
        </UserInfoContainer>
      </UserContainer>
      <ReviewStatusContainer>
        <Box>
          <Score />
          <Bar>
            <Progress progress={progress} color={dotColor} />
            <Dot />
            <Dot />
            <Dot />
            <Dot />
          </Bar>
        </Box>
        <ReviewStatusReachout>REACHOUT AGAIN</ReviewStatusReachout>
      </ReviewStatusContainer>
    </EachReview>
  )
}
export default OnGoingRequest

const EachReview = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2.5fr 1fr;
  padding: 25px 20px 15px 20px;
`
const UserContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`
const UserImage = styled.img``
const UserInfoContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
`
const UserName = styled.p`
  font-family: SFUIDisplay-Regular;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.19;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`
const UserProffession = styled.p`
  font-family: SFUIDisplay-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.21;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #6b737d;
  margin: 0;
`
const ReviewStatusContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
`
const ReviewStatusReachout = styled.p`
  font-family: SFUIDisplay-Regular;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.17;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  color: #30aabc;
  margin: 0;
`
const Box = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #63a3e3;
  text-align: center;
`
const Score = styled.div`
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 88px;
color: #fff;
}
`
const Bar = styled.div`
  background: #c4c4dd;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
`
const Progress = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in;
  width: ${props => props.progress};
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
  z-index: 1;
`
const Dot = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 5%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 16%;
  background-color: rgba(99, 163, 227, 1);
  /* background-color: rgba(199,12,127,.8);*/
  /*display: inline-block; */
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
```

progress is passed as props, and I am checking according to it but I get an error of too many re-renders. guess it's because of checking before the return.

Comment: Of course I have tried, I've been trying for some time now, the furthest I've gone is this:
const [dotColor, setDotColor] = useState('#c4c4dd')
  if (progress > 0 && progress <= 25) {
    setDotColor('red')
  } else if (progress > 25) {
    setDotColor('blue')
  }

progress is passed as props, and I am checking according to it but I get an error of too many re-renders.

Comment: You have to DEMONSTRATE your attempts and provide the neccesary code, HTML & CSS etc.

Comment: I really don't know how else can I demonstrate my attempts. I wrote the final code and which I am right now.
Do you want me to copy the whole component? I honestly don't know what else to do. 
I will just write the whole component in the edit post

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I recieve 1,2,3 or 4 as props and I am rendering according to it.

```
const OnGoingRequest = ({ image, name, profession, progress }) => {
  return (
    <EachReview>
      <UserContainer>
        <UserImage src={image} />
        <UserInfoContainer>
          <UserName>{name} </UserName>
          <UserProffession>{profession} </UserProffession>
        </UserInfoContainer>
      </UserContainer>
      <ReviewStatusContainer>
      {
        progress == 1 &&(
        <DotsContainer>
          <Dot color={'red'} />
        </DotsContainer>)
      }
      { progress === 2 && (
        <DotsContainer>
          <Dot color={'purple'} />
          <Dot color={'purple'} />
      </DotsContainer>
      )
      }
      {
        progress === 3 && (
          <DotsContainer>
            <Dot color={'yellow'} />
            <Dot color={'yellow'} />
            <Dot color={'yellow'} />
        </DotsContainer>
        ) 
      }
      {
        progress == 4 && ( 
        <DotsContainer>
          <Dot color={'green'} />
          <Dot color={'green'} />
          <Dot color={'green'} />
          <Dot color={'green'} />
        </DotsContainer>)
      }
        <ReviewStatusReachout>REACHOUT AGAIN</ReviewStatusReachout>
      </ReviewStatusContainer>
    </EachReview>
  )
}
export default OnGoingRequest

const EachReview = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.5fr 1fr;
  padding: 25px 20px 15px 20px;
`
const UserContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`
const UserImage = styled.img``
const UserInfoContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 10px;
`
const UserName = styled.p`
  font-family: SFUIDisplay-Regular;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.19;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`
const UserProffession = styled.p`
  font-family: SFUIDisplay-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.21;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #6b737d;
  margin: 0;
`
const ReviewStatusContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
`
const ReviewStatusReachout = styled.p`
  font-family: SFUIDisplay-Regular;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.17;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: right;
  color: #30aabc;
  margin: 0;
`

const DotsContainer = styled.div`
background: #fff;
position: relative;
height: 20px;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
text-align: left;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-evenly;
align-items: center;
`

const Dot = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
  /*display: inline-block; */
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-right: 10px;
  &:last-of-type{
    margin-right: 0;
  }
`
```